# SignalR handling server-side hardware events

Tags: javascript, c#, events, signalr, hardware

I have to develop a prototype application in C# using self-hosted SignalR 2.2.0  and a javascript client to listen for hardware events happening on the server side.
I have started by trying the chat sample application here: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/deployment/tutorial-signalr-self-host

The challenge is that on the server side the hardware events do not fire:

```
public class HardwareHub : Hub
{
    public void Send( string name, string message)
    {
        Clients.All.addMessage(name, message);
    }

    public void StartListeningHardwareEvents()
    {
        HardwareHandlingClass hhc = new HardwareHandlingClass();
        hhc.OnDeviceRemoved += new DeviceRemoved(OnDeviceRemoved);
    }

    OnDeviceRemoved( object sender, DecodedDataEventArgs e)
    {
        Send( "DeviceRemoved", e.Name);
    }
}
```

The two buttons on the client page are: "sendmessage" and "startlistening".

The sendmessage button works well, but the startlistening doesn't - the hardware events do not fire when using SignalR approach.
We tried also a windows forms application, since we thought the consoleApplication might be causing that behaviour, but when switching to signalR in the windows forms application the result is the same.

Any advice on why this might be happening or how to enable this is greatly appreciated. Any ideas?

Comment: Two points - 1) you create an instance in a method hook an event handler and exit the method - the `hhc` instance goes out of scope and the event won't be called; 2) Hubs instances are created for each request so you can't store the `HardwareHandlingClass` instance as a class variable.

Comment: There is a weird thing though. If I try to create a Timer instance as a class variable with an elapsed event - it works, it will write something every passed interval, but for the OnDeviceRemoved event it won't.

Concerning point 2) I think for know we are imagining something like a monitoring application with only one client that will be making requests and will wait for some event from the hardware before making a new request.

Comment: I think this can happen because the timer is still ticking after you lost the reference to it. Once it will be garbage collected it will stop invoking the callback. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.110).aspx: _As long as you are using a Timer, you must keep a reference to it. As with any managed object, a Timer is subject to garbage collection when there are no references to it. The fact that a Timer is still active does not prevent it from being collected._

Comment: @Pawel Thank you for your reply. Sorry if I'm bothering you still, but I do want to ask some more details, as I have been trying some tests by using a static instance of the HardwareHandlingClass both in the hub class and using a helper class, and it doesn't seem to make any difference. Is there anything else that I might have overlooked? 
We are using Windows 7 so SignalR will probably be using Server Sent Events as transport means

Comment: Hard to tell because this is a different setup and I don't know how it is wired. One thing that is not clear to me is how hhc.OnDeviceRemoved is being invoked. Another thing is that I don't know if you want to send notifications to all the clients - if so what's the purpose of `StartListeningHardwareEvents` - if you always send to all clients then this seems not needed - you could just call them from outside hub (e.g. from the HardwareHandlingClass instance like this: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#callfromoutsidehub